# Removing measure label from OpenLayers 3 measure?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have implemented the measure example available on the OpenLayers 3 site (http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.2/examples/measure.html) and I am currently trying to include a clear button that will clear both the drawn area / line and label from the map.

I've found the `getSource().clear()` option will clear the drawn shape from the map, but I am struggling to work out how I can clear the measurement label?

I have tried the `map.removeOverlay()` method with `'measureTooltip'` but this doesn't work.

How can I also remove this label from the map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you use jquery. if so do the following to remove the tooltips from map:

```
$( ".tooltip" ).remove();
```

this should remove every element with class 'tooltip' from document.
check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/yvn51mja/) it is from an older question. Within the fiddle the code snip adove is asigned when `drawstart` event occurs, because thats the way user wanted to be. You may place it within your function that clears the measures

Comment: I saw that example too. My view is there should be start and stop measure button apart from clear button to completely implement that flow. Will soon post my answer.

Comment: pavlos Fiddle is good but what if I want to draw both line and rectangle measure ?

Comment: I have just tried this and it removes both measurement options.

Comment: As said  remove the code snip from `drawstart` event and wrap it within your clear function. check the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/72he7hvd should be what you want

Comment: I have tried to implement this with a button click but after executing and then drawing a new a measurement no label appears. How can I make sure a new label shows? I added createMeasureTooltip after $( ".tooltip" ).remove(); but this doesn't work.

Comment: Although this method can work, I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null"

Answer (score 0):

Doing it without jQuery I used the following:

```
var staticTooltip = document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip-static")[0];
if (staticTooltip) {
  staticTooltip.parentNode.removeChild(staticTooltip);
  createMeasureTooltip();
}
```

I'm looking for "tooltip-static" class because the drawend event in the example sets the working tooltip to that class. And I create a new tooltip with `createMeasureTooltip()` so that future measures will have a tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

Without jquery, this worked for me, the statement "**while (staticTooltip.length> 0)**" selects all the measurements made, if your tool allows multiple measurements:

```
var staticTooltip = document.getElementsByClassName('tooltip-static');
            while(staticTooltip.length > 0){
                staticTooltip[0].parentNode.removeChild(staticTooltip[0]);
            }
```